# INSERT and SELECT on the same table in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query :

```
insert into service_parameters (
    services_f_service_id,
    parameter_type_f_type_id,
    value)
values ( 
    (select distinct services_f_service_id from service_parameters where value = 'XXX'), 
    1, 
    '<url>');
```

MySQL is complaining with the following error:

```
SQL Error [1093] [HY000]: You can't specify target table 'service_parameters' for update in FROM clause
```

Is there a way to achieve this without spliting the SQL statment into 2 ?!

Comment: What's the expected result if the subquery returns no rows at all, or if it returns several rows?

Comment: The subquery returns only one row, with one projection value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO service_parameters (
    services_f_service_id,
    parameter_type_f_type_id,
    value)
SELECT DISTINCT services_f_service_id,
                1, 
                '<url>'
FROM service_parameters 
WHERE value = 'XXX';
```

Comment: If this is selected the correct answer (which it is), then you need to clarify in your question that the INSERT can take more than 1 rows. Your current question (with the sample SQL of yours) definitely misleads us to think you are trying to INSERT only one row.

Comment: The number of rows doesn't really matter to me, because i know that the subquery will always give back 1 row.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a select command with no table here (make sure that the service_parameters has only one row for value='xxx'):

```
insert into service_parameters (
    services_f_service_id,
    parameter_type_f_type_id,
    value)
select
    (select distinct services_f_service_id from service_parameters where value = 'XXX'), 
    1, 
    '<url>';
```

;

Comment: Will fail if `(services_f_service_id, value)` is not unique.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error at: select distinct services_f_service_id try this:     `insert into service_parameters (services_f_service_id, parameter_type_f_type_id, value) values ((select distinct(services_f_service_id) from service_parameters where value = 'XXX'), 1, '<url>');`

Comment: Synthactically errorneous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).